# How can I measure time elapsed since a specific event triggered in my android app?

Tags: android

I have an app where the user gets a task every day so what is the best method to use to keep track of time for a period of a day including any system condition even if the user turned his phone off.

I found a suggestion to use SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() but it doesn't include the phone being turned off ... so any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this method once:

call this method by passing long value of your time

```
public static String getDateDifferenceInDays(long timeInMillis) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
        Date serverDate = new Date(timeInMillis * 1000L);
        Date localDate = new Date();
        String strDay = "";
        try {
            Date dateServer = simpleDateFormatParse.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(serverDate));
            Date dateLocal = simpleDateFormatParse.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(localDate));
            long diff = dateServer.getTime() - dateLocal.getTime();
            //Log.d(TAG, "server date-----" + dateServer + "-----local date----" + dateLocal);
            long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            //long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            if (days >= 0) {
                strDay = "Days left - " + days;
            } else {
                strDay = "Time elapsed";
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strDay;
```

Comment: This gets the difference between 2 dates in milliseconds ?

Comment: Even if the phone is switched off, the difference is accurately calculated ?

Comment: yes, of course, you are passing a date from the server and another one is getting locally when ever you visit that activity, in that scenario it will check server date and local date, and then find the difference. While calculating the difference your phone will be in ON condition right?

Comment: that's great !! :-) enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

Try to save (in `SharedPreferences` for example) the time of getting the task. Then when you want to get the period from this time to now you can do something like this:

```
long milliSecondsTriggering -> the milliseconds of the time of triggering the event;
long milliSecondsCurrentTime -> current time in milliseconds;
long periodSeconds = (milliSecondsCurrentTime - milliSecondsTriggering ) / 1000;
long elapsedDays = periodSeconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is what is the clock to use so I can get the current time knowing that the clock didn't stop because the phone was switched off

Comment: don't you have any code that is executed when the event is triggered? Just  save the time of triggering the event when you reach this code.